# Interpret summation when the lower limit is greater than the upper limit

Tags: summation, notation

Is there a rule for the following sum?
$$\sum_{k=t+1}^0 b_k$$

Basically, the lower limit is greater than the upper limit. Is this sum the same as $b_t + b_{t+1}$?

I read somewhere that $\prod_{k=t+1}^{t}b_k$ is defined as 1. If someone could explain this as well it would be great.

Comment: It looks either your $LATEX$ is not working properly or mine...

Comment: Sorry, I posted using phone, so wasn't able to use LaTeX.

Comment: You may refer to the answer to [this post][1]  [1]:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906511/interpreting-summation-with-fractional-part/1909120#1909120

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is customary to define any $\sum_{k=n}^m$ with $n>m$ as the empty sum, i.e. 0. More details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum

Similarly, it is customary to define $\prod_{k=n}^m$ with $n>m$ as the empty product, i.e. 1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product

It seems a little strange at first, but it actually turns out that a lot of things would break without these definitions.

Comment: Thanks for providing the sources. I was thinking of this from a programming point of view: the "loop" would never be executed in these cases, so it makes sense.