# Evaluating $\sum_{j=i+1}^n 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

We know that:
$$\sum_{j=0}^n j$$
we can evaluate it with the formula:
$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
so how would we evaluate this sum?
$$\sum_{j=i+1}^n 1$$

yes it is a $1$ and not $J$.

Comment: $n-i$ (if $i\le n$, otherwise it's $\max\{0,n-i\}$).

Comment: What is the value of $1 + 1 + \cdots + 1$ when you know how many summands of $1$'s there are?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio shouldn't it be $n - i$ only if $i < n$? 
If $i = n$, then the lower limit is greater than the upper limit.

Comment: @ILikeMathematics I don't see a problem. If $n=i$, then $\sum_{j=n+1}^n 1=0=n-n$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Oh, that's right.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at some examples and it will probably be clear.

Take $i = 1$, $n = 10$.

$\sum_\limits{j=i+1}^{n} 1 = \sum_\limits{j=2}^{10} 1 = \underbrace{1 + 1 + ... + 1}_{\text{9 times addition of 1}} = 9 = n - i $.

Now take $i = 2, n = 10$.

$\sum_\limits{j=i+1}^{n} 1 = \sum_\limits{j=3}^{10} 1 = \underbrace{1 + 1 + ... + 1}_{\text{8 times addition of 1}} = 8  = n - i$.

You can now formulate it in a more general way:

$\sum_\limits{j=i+1}^{n} 1 = \underbrace{1 + 1 + ... + 1}_{\text{n - i times addition of 1}} = n-i$.

This is for $n > i$, for $i \geq n$, it would be 0 since it would be an empty sum (see [Interpret summation when the lower limit is greater than the upper limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1517054/interpret-summation-when-the-lower-limit-is-greater-than-the-upper-limit)).